Do pet cats kept indoors live 10 years longer than indoor-outdoor pet cats?
I recently encountered the surprising claim that letting your cat go outdoors will shorten its lifespan by 10 years. I am wondering about the difference in lifespan between an indoor-only cat, and a pet cat that is cared for with a bed and food indoors but is allowed to go outside, henceforth called an "indoor-outdoor cat" (i.e. not a feral cat).
For example, K&H Pet Products say:

Outdoor cats tend to live an average of two to five years, sometimes longer. In contrast, indoor cats can live to be 17 years or older.1 The average life expectancy for indoor cats, however, is closer to 14 years.2

Two references were cited in that quote. The first is a dead link. The second says cats live 13-17 years, and that outdoor cats face dangers, and links to this article for the 2-5 year number, which does not cite a source.
Animal Emergency & Referral Center of Minnesota claims outdoor cats have a lifespan of 2-5 years, but there is no source cited. It is unclear if they are referring to outdoor-only or indoor-outdoor cats.
I see a Pets Stackexchange answer quoting WebMD. It says feral cats live 6 years. It also says outdoor cats live for 5 years (it isn't clear if they are referring to feral cats, outdoor-only cats or indoor-outdoor cats). The sources listed in that answer are dead links.
Of course, there are dangers outdoors that kill cats, such as cars, diseases, and coyotes, and there are other reasons not to let your cat outdoors, such as the number of birds they kill. I have an indoor cat. But is the difference in lifespan really that extreme, between indoor cats and indoor-outdoor cats? And what is the origin of the "2-5 years" number for outdoor cats that seems to come up a lot?
A note on terminology: An article advising (presumably indoor) cat owners not to let their cats outside unsupervised is advising them more precisely against having an indoor-outdoor cat. When such articles use the term "outdoor cat" to describe the harmful consequences of doing so, this lumps together the indoor-outdoor, outdoor-only, and feral categories. Not all sources making the claim lump these categories together; this source quotes a claim that "While the average out door or indoor-outdoor cat lives two to three years, an indoor-only cat's average life span is 12 to 15 years or more." The most precise categories are "indoor-only," "indoor-outdoor" (kept inside but allowed outside), and "outdoor-only" pet cats (e.g. tame barn cats), all of which would be distinguished from feral cats.

Reminder: Please post answers (with references) in the answer box. The comments aren't for answers or for what you hope the answer is.

Can you please include a reference that mentions indoor-outdoor cats? Maybe I missed it, but I only saw references to outdoor cats, so this appears to be a strawman.

@Oddthinking I found later https://www.wellbeingintlstudiesrepository.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1078&context=shesen (which I link in my answer) which makes the claim about "indoor-outdoor" cats. Maybe that link should go here but I did only find it later from trying to answer the question. But it's a matter of terminology not being fully standardized. The sources I link here use "outdoor cat" to refer to "a cat that is allowed unlimited and unsupervised outdoor access" which would be an "indoor-outdoor cat" by the definitions of the necropsy paper as long as the cat is allowed indoors.

The necropsy paper reserves "outdoor cat" for pet cats that are "outdoor-only" but not feral, e.g. barn cats. Also when I first heard the claim it was just someone talking about why they don't let their cats outside (can't link to that video as no permanent link exists) and if they did let their cats outside that would be indoor-outdoor.

Consider that the animal emergency and referral center is highly likely to experience a bias towards animals needing emergency care or neglected animals. The listed site makes no claim as to the group of pets they've studied, it only lists causes for death, which again they're biased towards. It is also unclear whether you accept a difference in owner care for their pet as an explanation for actual expected age differences; which can also introduce a bias between people who let a cat run outside and manage itself vs people who care for a cat enough that it's happy to stay inside voluntarily.

Looking at some papers now, I see this paper says

Most cats (83 percent) still remaining on-site at the end of the observation period had been present for >6 years. This compares favorably with the mean lifespan of 7.1 years reported for pet cats, particularly as almost half of the cats were first observed as adults of unknown age (Nassar 1984).
(Bottom of page 381)

Of course, that's a figure from 1984, and pet cats apparently live longer now with medical care. This article says "Life expectancy at age 0 for UK companion cats overall was 11.74 years."
This article says "Reported mean life spans in feral cats range from 2 to 8 years."
Longevity and mortality of cats attending primary care veterinary practices in England reports the median lifespan of English pet cats overall to be 14.0 years. It also contains the claim that 90% of English cats are allowed daily outdoor access (different from the US, where the figure given is 50-60%). So this would be inconsistent with indoor-outdoor cats having much shorter lifespans than indoor-only cats.
The only source I found directly comparing indoor-only cat lifespan to indoor-outdoor cat lifespan is Longevity and mortality in cats: A single institution necropsy study of 3108 cases (1989–2019) which says:

The median age at death for indoor only cats was 9.43 years (IQR 4.8–13.11 years, range 0.11–21.85 years) while the median age at death for indoor outdoor cats was 9.82 years (IQR 5.3–13.13 years, range 0.06–21.19 years) and the median age for outdoor cats was 7.25 years (IQR 1.78–11.92 years, range 0.12–20.64 years). These were statistically different (p = 0.0001) with outdoor cats having a shorter lifespan than either indoor only cats (p = 0.0001) or cats that lived indoor/outdoor (p<0.0001). There was no difference in the age of death between indoor only cats and those that lived indoor/outdoor. For cats ≥1 year of age, the median age of death for indoor cats was 9.98 years (IQR 6.14–13.46 years, range 1.01–21.85 years) while the median age of death for indoor outdoor cats was 10.09 years (IQR 6.29–13.35 years; range 1.00–21.19 years) and the median age of death for outdoor cats was 9.80 years (IQR 4.07–12.92 years). These differences were not statistically different (p = 0.11).

I think that largely answers the question. Indoor-outdoor cats in the sample studied do not have a significantly different lifespan from indoor cats.
However, the sample studied included only cats who were brought in to a veterinary hospital for a postmortem examination, which means it would not include cats that were never found - for example, cats that got lost or were eaten by coyotes. Perhaps we can try to correct for this to better estimate the true lifespan.
If X% of indoor-outdoor cats are lost and never found, then this could have in the worst case an X% reduction on the average age of death of those cats compared to what the study reported - the worst case being if they were lost at age 0. It would more likely be closer to X/2% if we assume chance of getting lost is independent of age. To estimate X I found this article which states, based on a random phone survey in 2010, that 15% of cat owners lost their cat in a five-year period and 70% of these lost cats are recovered, meaning roughly 5% of cats are lost and not found in a five-year period. This percentage would likely be higher for indoor-outdoor cats than cats in general, but we're still probably looking at single-digit percentages for lost-and-never-found in a five year period. So, if I'm guesstimating, this might account for a reduction in average lifespan of roughly 10% for indoor-outdoor cats compared to what the necropsy study reported.
Another criticism of this article is that it may be underreporting trauma deaths because a half-eaten cat would not be brought in for a necropsy exam. This is borne out by the fact it reports 4.7% of deaths due to trauma, while the study of English pet cats reports 12.2% of deaths to trauma. This under-reporting might have up to roughly a 7% impact on lifespan (the difference between the two figures) but there's also probably significant overlap between unreported cat trauma deaths and lost-and-never-found cats.

On the other side of things, tracking down the origin of the "outdoor cats die 10 years earlier than indoor cats" claim, the earliest article I found was from 1990 (non-scholarly). It says:

According to Barbara L. Diamond's article "Bringing the Outdoors In"
(Cat Fancy, April 1990), "While the average out door or indoor-outdoor cat lives two to three years, an indoor-only cat's average life span is 12 to 15 years or more."

It would be interesting to see what Diamond's article cites to see where these numbers originally came from, but I can't find it.

Nice find. This study looked only at cats that were brought into a veterinary hospital, so I wonder if they might be underestimating the proportion of cats who die from trauma. Their sample included 4.7% of cats who died from trauma, while they reference a study that looked at a broader population that found that "the most frequently attributed causes of mortality in cats of all ages were trauma (12.2%)...". Since indoor-outdoor cats might die of trauma (e.g., cars and coyotes) more frequently than indoor cats, this study might overestimate the lifespan of indoor-outdoor cats.

@Eonema, yes. In particular, the sample is of "Client-owned cats who underwent a post-mortem examination (n = 3,108) at a veterinary medical teaching hospital".  So the real conclusion should be that how the pet's owners treat them when sick or injured is independent of whether they are allowed outside.

@RayButterworth Ah, you're right. it's also not counting cats that were never found (eaten by coyotes, died miles from home, ran away and didn't come back, etc). So this is not conclusive. More information is needed.

Note also that the study is only those which underwent a post-mortem examination.  No such examination is likely to happen for a cat found half-eaten.

@Spitemaster Perhaps. That's echoing Eonema's comment. However, consider that the 12.2% trauma rate reported in https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1098612X14536176 is for the UK where (it is stated) 90% of cats have daily outdoor access. Around 70% of cats in the necropsy study had outdoor access, so we'd expect something like a 10% trauma death rate, and 4.7% was reported. So underreporting of trauma deaths probably only accounts for 10%-4.7% ~= 5% of deaths, with a corresponding 5% impact on average lifespan.

Nice, thank you and +1! I'm not sure it makes sense to have that final paragraph in the answer though. You already have it in the question, so having it in the answer suggests it is a new resource. And, anyway, that really isn't a very good source since none of its claims are supported by any references or data.

@terdon It's in kind of an uncomfortable spot. Initially it was in the answer only as the earliest source for the 10-year difference claim I found (1990), and I hadn't found it when I first asked the question. Not because it is scholarly but because it could be a clue where that claim originally came from. I was asked to add it to the question as evidence that those pushing the 10 year claim were referring to indoor-outdoor cats.

I get that, but since I read the question today and the answer today, and I hadn't even realized you were the author of both (you only see the answer's author when you get to the end of it), I thought it was a new resource and was confused to see it was just a repeat of what was in the question. And most people will be in my situation: they will see the Q&A as it is now, not as it was, so it might as well be consistent as it is now.

Much of the UK is basically a giant garden; its largest predators in any number are weasels and foxes.  Well, that and cars.

@Yakk as far as I am aware there are no predators in the UK that regularly prey on adult cats. Foxes will go for rabbits, rodents and hedgehogs but a cat is going to put up too much of a fight with its sharp claws to be an attractive meal. Weasels are smaller than cats, it's far more likely the cat will eat the weasel.

"the average out door or indoor-outdoor cat lives two to three years" sounds like a self-sourced (and self-serving) statistic.  It's certainly inconsistent with my personal experience as owner of several indoor/outdoor cats over the years (all the way back to the 70s), all of which lived much longer than that.

I wonder how or if new-born kittens are counted. A litter born outside is going to have a much lower survival rate than those born inside, for instance.
